# max-width not functioning correctly in flex-box on IE11

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

In IE11, if you define a width for a flex-box and a child `img` element has a `max-width` of 100%, it will not respect the `max-width`. Has anyone found a solution for this?

This works in IE10, Chrome, and Firefox but breaks for IE11:
http://jsfiddle.net/3ky60heq/

```css
.container {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 125px;
}

.image1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.image2,
.image3 {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <img class='image1' src="https://clagnut.com/sandbox/imagetests/wideimg.png">
</div>

<div class='container'>
  <img class='image2' src="https://clagnut.com/sandbox/imagetests/wideimg.png">
</div>

<div class='container'>
  <img class='image3' src="https://clagnut.com/sandbox/imagetests/smimg1.jpg">
</div>
```

I recognize this question has been asked before and has many different answers however every solution I found on StackOverflow or elsewhere either effectively forces the width of the image to 100% or breaks on other browsers.

Comment: IE11 has all sorts of bugs with the [Flexible Box Layout Module](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). Here is a [GitHub page](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs) documenting all know issues with flex-box that might help you.

Answer (score 3):

I think I have it figured out. 
If I set this style on the image:

```
flex-shrink: 0;
```

then it seems to work across the board.
http://jsfiddle.net/qgybon8q/2/

Comment: `flex-grow` is already 0, by default. `flex-basis` is already `auto`, another default. The only change you made was to `flex-shrink`, changing it from 1 (the default) to 0. That seems to do the trick (no idea why). So all you really need is `flex-shrink: 0`. Cool discovery.

Comment: Yup, I just noticed that. I updated the post.  Do you happen to know the best place to go to report the bug/workaround? And thanks for your help.

Comment: nice solution! +1