# Firefox not scaling img with max-width

Tags: css, image, width, flexbox

I find that img descendants of flexbox positioned items with max-width: 100% rule doesn't work on firefox.
I've tryed the solutions from:
[Firefox 34+ ignoring max-width for flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27472595/firefox-34-ignoring-max-width-for-flexbox)
and,
[Firefox flexbox image width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28710379/firefox-flexbox-image-width)

As the code is quite long I wrote a pen: http://codepen.io/vandervals/pen/raXBNj
As you can see in this pen, this is a problem for small sized screens. I found a not very elegant solution:

```
img{
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

The problem with this approach is that we lose the global use of the rule max-width: 100% for every image, no matter the actual dimensions of the image.
Has anyone solved this problem?