# The height of one div with flex display and overflow-y is not correct, cross the boundary in firefox 34.0, while it is correct in 31.3

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a html which works well in FireFox 31.3, while it breaks in FireFox 34.0.
I don't know it is flex problem in FF34, or overflow-y problem.

Following is the html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#main {
    width: 220px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}

#main .body{flex:1 1 auto; display:flex; flex-direction:row;}

#main .left{flex: 1;}

#main .right{flex:2; display:flex; flex-direction:column;}

#main .upper{flex:0 0 auto;}

#main .content{flex: 1 1 auto; overflow-y:auto;}

#main .footer{flex: 0 0 auto;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main">
  <div class="body">
  <div class = "left" style="background-color:coral;">RED</div>
  <div class ="right" style="background-color:lightblue;">
    <div class ="upper" style="background-color:yellow;"> UPPER </div>
    <div class ="content" style="background-color:lightyellow;"> 
       <ul>
         <li>a</li>
         <li>b</li>
         <li>a</li>
         <li>b</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
  </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="footer" style="background-color:lightgreen;">Green div with more content.</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

run this piece of code in FF31, the vertical scroll bar will be shown, everything is OK.
But run this piece of code in FF34, the vertical scroll bar will not be shown, the content will be shown cross the boundary.

Does anyone know how to walk around this?

Answer (score 0):

As I just noted in https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1118142 , you need to add "min-height:0" to your `#main .body` CSS rule.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26895349/how-can-i-get-ff-33-x-flexbox-behavior-in-ff-35-x/26916542#26916542) for more info.