# How can I normalize the implied minimum width of flex-items across the latest versions of major browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

**Edit** This may be close to a duplicate, but unfortunately the answer to that question does nothing for IE 11. IE is an implied requirement for a question asking for a cross-browser solution.

I've got a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bodine30/pgxy8f5x) showing the issue.

The first `.flex-container` is closest to how things are built in my application. This renders "correctly" in chrome, but if you pull it up in IE 11, or Firefox ≈38 the inputs overflow the parent `.flex-container`.

This issue doesn't seem to listed among the [known issues on caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox). I can't directly attribute it to one of [these flexbugs](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs) either.

Can somebody please shed some light on this inconsistency?

Here is an image of Chrome's rendering:
[image]

and here is one from IE 11:
[image]

I've tried paring the example down with the subsequent containers, and the inputs seem to be the problem. The exception is in the second Chrome container where the existence of the `<label>` element seems to throw off the width calculation slightly.

I really don't want to define widths on the immediate children of `.flex-container` if I don't have to. I'd like to use the simplicity of the `flex-grow` property so that I can add children at some later point.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you see the link to my jsfiddle? You can play around with it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/bodine30/pgxy8f5x/

Comment: Sorry I must have missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Flexbox module changes the initial value of `min-width`:

> [**4.5 Implied Minimum Size of Flex Items**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto)
>
> To provide a more reasonable default minimum size for [flex items](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item),
>   this specification introduces a new [auto](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-min-width-min-height-auto) value as the initial
>   value of the [min-width](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-min-width) and [min-height](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-min-height) properties defined in
>   CSS 2.1.

Chrome hasn't implemented it yet, that's why it seems to work there.

On Firefox, you can fix it using [How can I get FF 33.x Flexbox behavior in FF 34.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26895349/1529630)

```css
@import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css';
@import 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.min.css';
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
body {
  font-family:"Segoe UI", "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  background-color: #424242;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex-container, .input-group, .input-group-btn {
  display:flex;
}
.flex-container {
  width:600px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1.6rem;
  margin: 1.6rem;
}
.flex-container > * + * {
  margin-left: 2.5rem;
}
label {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  color:white;
}
.form-control {
  flex-grow:1;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0.6rem 12px;
  border:0 none;
  text-align:center;
}
.input-group-btn {
  flex-basis: 62px;
  flex-shrink:0;
}
.input-group-btn button.btn {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink:0;
  border: 0 none
}
.input-group-btn > .btn {
  position: relative;
}
.form-control, .input-group-btn .btn {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
}
.input-group .input-group-btn > .btn {
  border-top: 0 none;
  border-bottom: 0 none;
}
.flex-item {
  background: white;
  height: 50px;
}
.flex-container > * {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  min-width: 0;
}
.form-control {
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Start Date</label>
    <div class="input-group date date-picker">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yy"/>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
          <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </button> 
      </span> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">End Date</label>
    <div class="input-group date date-picker">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yy" /> 
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
          <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </button> 
      </span> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Start Date</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="start-date" type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yy" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">End Date</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="end-date" type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yy" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <input class="form-control" name="start-date" type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yy" />
  <input class="form-control" name="end-date" type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yy" />
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">asdf</div>
  <div class="flex-item">asdf</div>
</div>
```

However, IE needs other changes:

```css
.flex-container > * {
  flex: 1; /* Use `flex-basis: 0%` instead of your `auto` */
}
.form-control {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
@import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css';
@import 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.min.css';
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
body {
  font-family:"Segoe UI", "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  background-color: #424242;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex-container, .input-group, .input-group-btn {
  display:flex;
}
.flex-container {
  width:600px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1.6rem;
  margin: 1.6rem;
}
.flex-container > * + * {
  margin-left: 2.5rem;
}
label {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  color:white;
}
.form-control {
  flex-grow:1;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0.6rem 12px;
  border:0 none;
  text-align:center;
}
.input-group-btn {
  flex-basis: 62px;
  flex-shrink:0;
}
.input-group-btn button.btn {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink:0;
  border: 0 none
}
.input-group-btn > .btn {
  position: relative;
}
.form-control, .input-group-btn .btn {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
}
.input-group .input-group-btn > .btn {
  border-top: 0 none;
  border-bottom: 0 none;
}
.flex-item {
  background: white;
  height: 50px;
}
.flex-container > * {
  flex: 1;
}
.form-control {
  min-width: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Start Date</label>
    <div class="input-group date date-picker">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yy"/>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
          <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </button> 
      </span> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">End Date</label>
    <div class="input-group date date-picker">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yy" /> 
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
          <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </button> 
      </span> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Start Date</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="start-date" type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yy" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">End Date</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="end-date" type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yy" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <input class="form-control" name="start-date" type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yy" />
  <input class="form-control" name="end-date" type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yy" />
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">asdf</div>
  <div class="flex-item">asdf</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this seems to have no effect on IE. Any idea why?

Comment: @bodine It seems the problem was with `flex-basis: auto` and form controls without explicit width, which could be a recursive definition.