# How to arrange three flex div side by side

Tags: html, css

[image: divs]

I have three divs in content div, When browser resizing

- blue and red div must have their fixed width
- green div must resize to left space

I also tried this in css

```
.yellow{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.red{
    height: 100%;
    width:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: red;
}
.green{
    height: 100%;
    min-width:400px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:green;
}
.blue{
    height: 100%;
    width:400px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

This code does not resize green div, In some browsers red panel not showing

I also tried `float: left` and

```
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
```

but not working correctly. How to do this?

Comment: This could help: http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/holy-grail/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `flex-grow`. Set it to 0 for the blue and red container, and something big for the green one:

```
.red{
    height: 100%;
    width:200px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: red;
}
.green{
    height: 100%;
    min-width:400px;
    flex-grow: 1000;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:green;
}
.blue{
    height: 100%;
    width:400px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

A very good cheat sheet can be found here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Also, don't forget the other properties like `display: flex;`and `justify-content: space-between`. It's perfectly explained in the above link.

Note, however, that you don't have to use flexbox. you can achieve the same with `float`, which makes it compatible with older browsers (To do so, just use `display: block;` and add `float: left` to the blue div and `float: right;` to the red one.)

Comment: That is a really great link. The content is very explained really well.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `flex` shorthand property, which defines the flexible behavior of an item:

```css
.yellow { display: flex } /* Magic begins */
.red, .green, .blue { min-width: 0 } /* See http://stackoverflow.com/q/26895349/ */
.red { flex: 0 200px } /* Initial width of 200, won't grow, can shrink if necessary */
.green { flex: 400px } /* Initial width of 400, grows to fill available space, can shrink if necessary */
.blue { flex: 0 400px } /* Initial width of 400, won't grow, can shrink if necessary */
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.yellow {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}
.red, .green, .blue {
  min-width: 0;
}
.red {
  flex: 0 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  flex: 400px;
  background-color:green;
}
.blue {
  flex: 0 400px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="yellow">
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: does different browsers support flex shorthand property?

Comment: @Thusitha All browsers that support flexbox should support `flex`.