# Three elements side-by-side in flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to position three elements side-by-side using flexbox, but the `align-self` properties are having no effect. I'm not using `space-around` or `space-between` on the parent (`#subnav-cont`) because each element needs to be positioned individually since the far-left element (`#site-logo`) is not always present.

To recap, `#site-logo` should sit on the far-left (*when present*), `#site-links` should be centered in relation to its parent, and `#nav-social` should sit on the far-right.

Demo: http://codepen.io/ourcore/pen/jyBNzZ

```css
#subnav {
  z-index: 99999999;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#subnav #subnav-cont {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1.5%;
  max-width: 1280px;
  background-color: red;
}
#subnav #subnav-cont #site-logo {
  align-self: flex-start;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 50px;
}
#subnav #subnav-cont #site-logo img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 30px;
}
#subnav #subnav-cont > ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#subnav #subnav-cont #nav-links {
  align-self: center;
}
#subnav #subnav-cont #nav-social {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
#subnav #subnav-cont #nav-social li {
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="subnav">
  <div id="subnav-cont">
    <div id="site-logo">
      <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
    </div>
    <ul id="nav-links">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="subnav-link">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="subnav-link">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="subnav-link">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="subnav-link">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="nav-social">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="icon-facebook">Facebook</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="icon-twitter">Twitter</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="icon-instagram">Instagram</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Add a width to each of your elements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to arrange three flex div side by side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31476024/how-to-arrange-three-flex-div-side-by-side)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan This statement, _since the far-left element (#site-logo) is not always present._ makes it not a dupe of that question

Comment: So, as usual, when something is proposed as a duplicate, editing the question to make it more clear why it's not a duplicate is a good idea... I've done that for future readers.

Comment: Now I got surprised .... how does the accepted answer make _`#site-links` should be centered in relation to its parent,_ ???

Comment: I accidentally accepted it. I None of the answer place `#nav-links` perfectly centered, which is what I'm trying to achieve, regardless of its adjacent elements. I also can't use static widths because they will vary.

Comment: So how will the left and right elements width change? .. even or different or ..?

Comment: `#subnav-cont` has padding of 1.5%, so `#site-logo` and `#nav-social` should be pressed up against these margins, while `#nav-links` should be centered within `#subnav-cont`, not within `#site-logo` and `#nav-social`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were looking for `justify-self` but that doesn't exist in flexbox. `align-self` works on cross-axis.

Try this:

```
#nav-links {
  margin: auto;
}
```

**[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rjyNEL)**

If you need `#nav-links` to be centered within `#subnav-con`, regardless if the other two elements are present and their widths. You can set it to `position: absolute;` along with other tweaks.

```
#nav-links {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

**[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJpYPo)**

Comment: This is very close to what I'm trying to achieve, but I can't tell if `#nav-links` is exactly centered. Also, this only works when `#site-logo` is present. Otherwise, `#nav-links` shifts to the left.

Comment: @MarioParra it's only centered in the space it takes, unless the left and right items are the same width. Do you need it to be centered in the viewport width?

Comment: I need #nav-links to be centered within `#subnav-con`, regardless if the other two elements are present and their widths.

Comment: @MarioParra Updated above, let me know.

Comment: I wanted to avoid using absolute positioning and thought I could benefit from flexbox's dynamic layouts, but this is the closest answer to what I'm looking for so far.

Comment: @MarioParra I agree that flexbox is not like the super hero that can solve everything, you can achieve that layout just fine without it.

Comment: @Pangloss Agree on that :)

Comment: Almost used this, but the layout breaks when `#site-logo` isn't present (`#nav-social` jumps to the far-left). This is why I tried controlling the position of each element independently.

Comment: @MarioParra Just add `#nav-social {margin-left: auto;}` that should be fixed.

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks! Will accept this answer. Can you explain how this works?

Comment: @MarioParra See this great article on [Medium](https://medium.com/@samserif/flexbox-s-best-kept-secret-bd3d892826b6#.48e8unak8).

Answer (score 1):

`align-self` in this case adjust the item vertically.

Is this what you are looking for?

Also, for this to work properly, both the `#site-logo` and `#nav-social` needs to be equal width, and if not, the `#nav-links` needs to be positioned in another way, i.e. `position: absolute`

```css
#subnav {
  z-index: 99999999;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#subnav #subnav-cont {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1.5%;
  max-width: 1280px;
  background-color: red;
}
#subnav #subnav-cont #site-logo {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 50px;
  /*visibility: hidden;*/
  text-align: left;
}
#subnav #subnav-cont #site-logo img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 30px;
}
#subnav #subnav-cont > ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#subnav #subnav-cont #nav-links {
  flex: 2;
  text-align: center;
}
#subnav #subnav-cont #nav-social {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}
#subnav #subnav-cont #nav-social li {
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="subnav">
    <div id="subnav-cont">
      <div id="site-logo">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
      </div>
      <ul id="nav-links">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="subnav-link">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="subnav-link">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="subnav-link">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="subnav-link">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="nav-social">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="icon-facebook">Facebook</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="icon-twitter">Twitter</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="icon-instagram">Instagram</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: In both examples, the far-left (`#site-logo`) and far-right (`#nav-social`) elements are not flush against the edges,

Comment: @MarioParra Outer edges ?

Comment: The edges of `#subnav-cont`.

Comment: @MarioParra Updated my answer. Better?

Comment: @MarioParra Also, for this to work properly, both the #site-logo and #nav-social needs to be equal width, and if not, the #nav-links needs to be positioned in another way

Comment: Ideally, I want each element to occupy whatever width is necessary, which is why I'm using flexbox.

Comment: @MarioParra Yes, get that, though since flex items adjust to its content and `flex-grow` expand based on what is left when content consumed its space, having 2 outer elements with different width you won't be able to center the middle 100% accurate.

Comment: I see. I may have to use the answer with absolute positioning.

Comment: @MarioParra Made a 2:nd update ... where I played with the `flex: nn` values some, maybe this can be a compromise?