# How can I force a nested flexbox element to shrink and display a scrollbar when the viewport resizes?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm building a layout using flexbox, and it's fairly simple overall. There are three parts of the view: a navigation bar at the top, a sidebar on the left, and a content area that fills the remaining space. The navigation bar has a fixed height, and the sidebar has a fixed width.

Furthermore, the sidebar and content areas should scroll individually. If the content in the sidebar overflows, it should create a scrollbar specific to the sidebar. The same is true with the content view. Importantly, this means that the overall viewport must never scroll: it should remain static (only the elements should scroll).

Building this layout is very simple with flexbox:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#root {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

#frame {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#navigation-bar {
  background-color: #bab;
  display: flex;
  height: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

#left-bar {
  background-color: #aaa;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 250px;
}

#content {
  background-color: #ccc;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div id="frame">
    <div id="navigation-bar">
      <h1>Website Name</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="left-bar">
        <h1>Some content</h1>
        <h1>Some content</h1>
        <h1>Some content</h1>
        <h1>Some content</h1>
        <h1>Some content</h1>
        <h1>Some content</h1>
        <h1>Some content</h1>
        <h1>Some content</h1>
        <h1>Some content</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, notice that the sidebar does *not* scroll individually. Instead, the whole viewport expands and scrolls. Interestingly, what I'm trying to achieve works properly without the nesting—if I remove the navigation bar, the sidebar scrolls independently.

How can I prevent the flexbox itself from stretching to contain its contents so that the element-specific scrollbar is displayed, not the viewport's scrollbar?

Comment: Alright, I ran your code snippet, but it appears to work just fine on that. The sidebar scrolls, nothing else does. I am clearly missing something

Comment: @DauntlessRob Interesting! Could I ask you what browser you're running? It could be a browser difference.

Comment: I'm running chrome 43.0.2357.134 on a mac. I just ran the file in the wild as well and it worked fine. I'll try it in some other browsers. What browser are you on?

Comment: @DauntlessRob Bizarre, I've tried it on both Safari and Chrome on Mac. Could you post a screenshot of what you see? Maybe we're seeing the same thing and someone's just misunderstanding.

Comment: Possible, but I totally see the problem when I run it on my Firefox (developer). http://imgur.com/eKaECxj

Comment: First image is Firefox, second is Chrome: http://imgur.com/jVAoTYc,DEj6M4c

This is a really strange quirk you've found....

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add this:

```css
#main {
  min-height: 0;
  flex: 1 1 0;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#root {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}
#frame {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#navigation-bar {
  background-color: #bab;
  display: flex;
  height: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0;
  min-height: 0;
}
#left-bar {
  background-color: #aaa;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 250px;
}
#content {
  background-color: #ccc;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div id="frame">
    <div id="navigation-bar">
      <h1>Website Name</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="left-bar">
        <h1>Some content</h1>
        <h1>Some content</h1>
        <h1>Some content</h1>
        <h1>Some content</h1>
        <h1>Some content</h1>
        <h1>Some content</h1>
        <h1>Some content</h1>
        <h1>Some content</h1>
        <h1>Some content</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You need `min-height: 0` because, as explained in [How can I get FF 33.x Flexbox behavior in FF 34.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26895349/1529630), the Flexbox module changes the initial value of `min-height`:

> [**4.5 Implied Minimum Size of Flex Items**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto)
>
> To provide a more reasonable default minimum size for [flex items](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item),
>   this specification introduces a new [auto](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-min-width-min-height-auto) value as the initial
>   value of the [min-width](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-min-width) and [min-height](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-min-height) properties defined in
>   CSS 2.1.

I also added `flex: 1 1 0` because `flex: 1` becomes `flex: 1 1 0%`, but that `0%` is buggy on Chrome in a column layout. But `0` works well.

Comment: Hmm. This works great [on Chrome](http://i.stack.imgur.com/T1oTC.png), but it still doesn't work [on Safari](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4LuS2.png).

Comment: @AlexisKing Does that include my edit with `flex: 1 1 0`?

Comment: I just added your change, and unfortunately, it still doesn't work properly on Safari.

Comment: @AlexisKing Strange, and I don't have Safari to test. Try `#main{overflow:hidden}`

Comment: Oh! Nevermind, I need to prefix with `-webkit-` on Safari. My mistake. This seems to work great—let me see if it fixes my problem (either way, it addresses this question).

Comment: "Flex" is a shorthand for:  flex-grow | flex-shrink | flex-basis.