# Flex items are not wrapping in webkit if flex-basis is set in %

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flex container with 5 items set to `flex(1 1 20%)`. Each item has the same width (initially set to have 20% width of the container). All good.

```
.container {
    display: flex
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
    flex: 1 1 20%;
}
```

I am expecting the items to wrap (see http://jsfiddle.net/edag6amx/4/), but I can't get it working under Safari or Chrome. Works well in FF and Edge.

If I change the item's `flex-basis` to `auto` (`flex: 1 1 auto`) it will start wrapping as expected.

Any suggestions please?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an image of what you're expecting? On FF the 5th item goes under

Comment: The wrapping is expexted. In my opinion the FF behaves correctly. Point is it does not wrap under Chrome.

Comment: So the `flex: 1 1 25%;` is more accurate?

Comment: It's not about the actual percentage (see this 50% example http://jsfiddle.net/edag6amx/6/) - point is that if you resize narrow enough the items will **not** wrap.

Comment: For me, it's ok not to wrap. 20% * 5 = 100% -> they fit.  Am i missing something ?

Comment: I've tried this http://jsfiddle.net/edag6amx/7/ ul add `flex-flow: row wrap;` and on li `flex: auto;`

Comment: @vals I should have emphasized that the wrapping is only expected if you narrow you browser enough. You are correct that it should not wrap if there is enough room. I though it to be obvious.

Comment: @romuleald - yes, I have mentioned that in my original post, that setting to ```auto``` works. Problem with that is that as soon as you don't have same item content the width of the items will not be equal: http://jsfiddle.net/edag6amx/9/

Comment: Adding a min-width and flex auto looks like a solution? But it's not really flexible. I'm pretty sure that a solution exist, but still not explored.

Comment: In Gecko they wrap because of the new `min-width: auto`. Webkit hasn't implemented it yet, so uses `min-width: 0`. Basically, you want the opposite of [How can I get FF 33.x Flexbox behavior in FF 34.x?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26895349/1529630)

Answer (score 0):

**Have flex-shrink set to 0**

```
.container {
    display: flex
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
    flex: 1 0 20%;
}
```