# Fix width of a flex column based on another

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a wrapper of `500px` and 2 columns. The second column is `200px` width (`flex: 0 0 200px`).

If in the first there is an element `> 300px` the first column will expand according to this element.

How can I stop the first column from growing, basing only the width of the wrapper and the second column?

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/b58aatdr/3/

```css
#hello {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
}
#hello > div {
  height: 50px;
}
#hello > div:first-child {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#hello > div:last-child {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 0 200px;
}
#baddiv {
  width: 400px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="hello">
  <div>
    <div id="baddiv"></div>
  </div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you have a problem with your code, your question needs to contain an [MCVE].  And unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, **only provide the compiled CSS (and the necessary HTML to reproduce the problem)**.

Comment: Done https://jsfiddle.net/b58aatdr/3/

Comment: You fail pretty hard at reading, the code has to be **in the question itself**.

Comment: `min-width: 0`? See [How can I get FF 33.x Flexbox behavior in FF 34.x?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26895349/1529630)

Comment: @Oriol OP looks for a solution where not to have to give the first column any width, it should use its parent + right sibling to set the max width for the first column ... and I'm now trying to get an answer why. ... Also my answer cover the 2 ways how to do that, though I suggest to use max-width on the first column if to keep `flex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `max-width: 300px` to your first div if you want it to adjust itself up to 300px and use `width: 300px;` if you want it to always be 300px even if content is less wide.

*Update based on comment*

The 2:nd div group uses another trick, `position: absolute`, where one doesn't need to set any width, it uses the parent and the right div to restrict the left div from growing beyond the 300px.

Note also, this is a normal behavior how element works, if they don't have a fixed/max width set, they grow (or in some cases wrap) to fit their content.

*Update 2 based on comment*

The 3:rd div group uses `display: table` instead of `flex`, where one doesn't need to set any width.

```css
.hello {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
}
.hello > div {
  height: 50px;
}
.hello > div:last-child {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 0 200px;
}
.baddiv {
  width: 400px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: purple;
}

/* alt. 1 */
.hello.nr1 > div:first-child {
  background-color: yellow;
  max-width: 300px;
}

/* alt. 2 */
.hello.nr2 > div:first-child {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  background-color: lime;
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* alt. 3 */
.hello.nr3 {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 500px;
}
.hello.nr3 > div {
  height: 50px;
  display: table-cell;
}
.hello.nr3 > div:first-child {
  background-color: cyan;
}
.hello.nr3 > div:last-child {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hello nr1">
  <div>
    <div class="baddiv"></div>
  </div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="hello nr2">
  <div>
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="baddiv">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="hello nr3">
  <div>
    <div class="baddiv"></div>
  </div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was searching for a solution that not includes the set of the first div's width... otherwise yes, it could be a solution

Comment: @OscarFanelli Using `max-width` is the way to tell an element to not go wider than a certain value (so you don't set it to anything, just tell when to stop). How else do you think it should know when to stop?

Comment: Thanks to it's div parent and div brother

Comment: @OscarFanelli I updated my answer with a second sample, which does what you ask, though if you ask me, the 1:st is preferred as it has less markup and therefore becomes cleaner.

Comment: Thanks @LGSon, it's not the solution that I was searching for, maybe there is another one, but I think for now I will use your first solution ;)

Comment: @OscarFanelli I updated my answer with a 3:rd sample, which does what you ask, without any extra markup, where I used `display: table`. Now there are no other way to do it, without setting a width to the 1:st div. .. May I ask why you need a solution where width/max width must not be set?

Comment: Thanks @LGSon! This is great :)

Comment: to make everything more clean and re-usable