# Understanding the behavior of overflow: hidden in a flexbox container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've been having a few issues with flex boxes and having them span out of their container as the text/content grows, and only applying ellipses when a specified max-width of the container is reached.

This isn't ideal because the parent container can shrink to x pixels and the text just forces it to grow to the max-width which I do not want.

Looking at [**this fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pyefqang/3/),
if I remove `overflow: hidden` from `child1` and apply it to `main`, the text will just be cut off.

If I remove `overflow: hidden` from `main` and apply it to `child1`, the behaviour I want is achieved.

If I remove `overflow: hidden` from both of them, the container and text just go on forever.

*I just want to know why applying `overflow: hidden` to `child1` produces the desired behaviour. Shouldn't the text just cut off as it did with overflow on `main`?*

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  //overflow: hidden;

}
.child1 {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.child2 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="child1">
    <div class="child2">
      Lots of words Lots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you remove overflow from child1 and apply it to main you will notice that child1 width will now be larger than main.  This appears to be due to child2 (lots of text) pushing the width (since there is no longer an overflow).  Child1 is now being cut by main but child2 has nothing preventing his expansion

Comment: Related: [How can I get FF 33.x Flexbox behavior in FF 34.x?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26895349/1529630)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you apply `overflow: hidden` to `.main`, this clips `.child1` *but not `.child2` (the div with text)*.

So `.child2` overflows `.main` because there is no `overflow: hidden` on `.child1` ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pyefqang/5/)).

To understand this better, try `overflow: scroll` on `.main` instead of `hidden`.

When you use `overflow: hidden` on `.child1`, this clips `.child2`.

Now the width of `.child2` is limited, and ellipsis works as intended ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pyefqang/6/)).

Again, this can be illustrated more clearly with `overflow: scroll` on `.main`.

Also keep in mind, the `overflow` property applies only to content of a block container.

*From the spec:*

> [**11.1.1 Overflow: the `overflow`
>   property**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visufx.html#overflow)
>
> This property specifies whether content of a block container element
>   is clipped when it overflows the element's box. It affects the
>   clipping of all of the element's content except any descendant
>   elements (and their respective content and descendants) whose
>   containing block is the viewport or an ancestor of the element.

Comment: Just a quick question, if I change the markup to this https://jsfiddle.net/pyefqang/8/ with `child2` now just being a block with a ridiculous width, why is it bound within child1? shouldn't it still span to a crazy width but clipped off when it reaches the edge of `child1` instead of being cound by it

Comment: Because (1) There is no content. As stated in the spec (see my answer), the `overflow` property applies only to content, and (2) You need to add `white-space: nowrap`. The initial value of the `white-space` property is `normal`, which means content is allow to wrap. https://jsfiddle.net/pyefqang/9/

Answer (score 16):

That's because Flexbox introduces a new initial value for `min-width` and `min-height`: `auto`.

When you have the initial `overflow: visible`, `min-width: auto` computes to the width of the contents of the flex item (see the [exact rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto)).

But when you use a different `overflow`, `min-width: auto` will compute to `0`.

In your case, `.child1` is a flex item. So by default it will be at least as wide as its contents. It can even overflow its container, in that case `.main`'s `overflow` will be taken into account.

But if you want to prevent `.main` from growing too much, you can

- Use a non-`visible` `overflow`, as you observed. This will make `min-width: auto`  compute to `0`.

  ```css
  .main {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .child1 {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 100px;
  }
  .child2 {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    text-align: center;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="main">
    <div class="child1">
      <div class="child2">
        Lots of words Lots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```
- Don't make `.child` a flex item. This will make `min-width: auto` compute to `0`.

  ```css
  .main {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .child1 {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 100px;
  }
  .child2 {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    text-align: center;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="main">
    <div class="child1">
      <div class="child2">
        Lots of words Lots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```
- Set `min-width: 0` manually

  ```css
  .main {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .child1 {
    min-width: 0;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 100px;
  }
  .child2 {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    text-align: center;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="main">
    <div class="child1">
      <div class="child2">
        Lots of words Lots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of wordsLots of
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: thank you SO MUCH. i was going crazy trying to figure out why changing `overflow` seemed to have repercussions on the height of the flex item

Comment: **Thank you very much!** I just discovered that `overflow: hidden;` has a magical effect on a flex item's width, and then I found your explanation that totally answered my question.